# Regex pattern to extract user id from a string

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I am using google's big query and I am trying to find the regex pattern to extract the userid from a string the userid looks something like this:

```
{"user":"324f65gsaygvsdf54554165sdfsd5"}
```

The complete string looks some thing like this:

```
{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"flash":{},"passport":{"user":"324f65gsaygvsdf54554165sdfsd5"},"afterDiscovery":"https://somecompany.com","dashboard":"gbslfdchgddjfgrrgtgjhds5555","authorize":{}}
```

Comment: To get the ID only : `/"user":"(.*?)"/`. Even though it would still be better to parse your object then explore its properties to access the value you want.

Comment: Thanks @Seblor that worked well with a bit of adjustment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having that your data is presented as json string - you can use [`JSON`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#json-functions) functions instead of [`REGEXP`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract) functions

Below example is for BigQuery StandardSQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH t AS(
  SELECT '{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"flash":{},"passport":{"user":"324f65gsaygvsdf54554165sdfsd5"},"afterDiscovery":"https://somecompany.com","dashboard":"gbslfdchgddjfgrrgtgjhds5555","authorize":{}}' json
)
SELECT json_extract_scalar(json, '$.passport.user') AS userid
FROM t
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not tell us much.  For example, what kind of regex engine you are actually using:

For *PCRE* you could use to pick the userid (based on your example, I presume that all characters are either numbers or lower case chars):

`(?<="user":")[a-z1-9]+`

`(?<="user":")` - looks behind and tries to find "user":" before actual maching (excluding the find out of the match)

`[a-z1-9]+` - matching at least one (one to many) lowercase character combined with numbers

Comment: tried that but bigquery doesn't support revers matching with regex

Comment: @Marlon Gray That is why I was talking about the regex engine.